# how can I parse a return from elasticsearch using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, elasticsearch

I make an api call to and Elasticsearch cluster like this:

```
app.get('/search', (req, resp) => {
  client.search({
    index: 'elastic-products',
     body: {
      query: {
        match: {
          product: 'key-ring'
        }
      }
    }
  }).then(function (data) {
      var hits = data.hits.hits;
      console.log(hits);
      return resp.render('search', {hits});
  }, function (err) {
      console.trace(err.message);
  });
  })
```

It successfully returns the following which is printed in the console:

```
listening on port 3000 ... 
[
  {
    _index: 'elastic-products',
    _type: '_doc',
    _id: 'gwIK53IBo-7CHg6T5Qe7',
    _score: 2.97042,
    _source: {
      merchant_id: '3QIE53IBo-7CHg6TUwaj',
      product: 'key-ring',
      price: '1.99',
      description: 'none',
      image_url: 'not available',
      timestamp: '2020-06-24T16:55:50.150527'
    }
  }
]
GET /search 200 26 - 439.200 ms
```

I want to pass the object to the index page with

```
return resp.render('search', {hits});
```

so that I can then parse it and print it out in HTML, on the index.ejs page, like so:

```
<%= hits._source.price %>
```

but this does not work. The error message is:

```
(node:1485) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
    at /Users/...../app.js:40:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:1485) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1485) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How can I pass the result of an api call like this to a different page and parse it to print into an HTML page? Thank you.

Comment: `hits` is an array by the looks of it, so `hits[0]._source.price`?

Comment: thank you, so simple. Works now. Separately, is there an equivalent to Python json.dumps in node?

Comment: If you're  looking to serialize/de-serialize JSON objects there's `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` methods available.

Or are you looking for something else?